# How can I get the correct type if I access an object property with a string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following code:

```
interface Response { 'property.a': number; 'property.b': string }
const response: Response = {
  'property.a': 10,
  'property.b': 'foo'
}
```

I want to access the properties of `response` in a type-safe way, but it doesn't completely work as I would expect. What I am looking for is a way of accessing object properties with strings, where

1. If the object has the property, accessing it gives the correct type
2. If the object does not have the property, accessing it throws an error

If you access the properties directly, this is what happens:

```
response['property.a'] // works as expected: is of type number
response['property.c'] // should throw an error, but doesn't
```

So condition 1 is satisfied, but condition 2 isn't. I also tried the following:

```
const get = <T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) => obj[key]
get(response, 'property.a') // should be of type number, but is number | string;
get(response, 'property.c') // works as expected: throws error
```

So at least throws the error, but now it returns a union of all possible property types in `Response`- this method fails on condition 1, but satisfies condition 2.

Is there a method that satisfies both conditions?

EDIT:

I just figured out that there is a TypeScript rule called `noImplicitAny` that enabled this kind of behavior! Unfortunately I can't enable this rule in the codebase I'm currently working in, so I'll keep this question open in case there's another workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For direct property access you should definitely get an error unless you don't have [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) enabled, which is part of the "standard" [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  It is almost universally recommended to enable `--strict`.

---

Taking about your `get()` function method:

Since `key` is of type `keyof T`, then `obj[key]` will be of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[keyof T]`, which is going to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all known property types in `T`.

If you want to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the specific key passed in as the `key` parameter, then your `get()` function needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type, like this:

```
const get = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key]
```

Now `key` is of generic type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T`, and `obj[key]` is inferred to be of the indexed access type `T[K]`.  Let's test it:

```
const num = get(response, 'property.a');
// const num: number
```

Here, `T` is inferred to be `Response` and `K` is inferred to be `"property.a"`, and so `T[K]` is `number`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxA9mpBvAUE-SAlsAC4QBOAZgsgErQxrBTJZIDkM5aMFJAngDoQ7AFxJgAVzAAjCgG4OXHnyEyxSKCXLEA5kgC+eAvCZak5BmYjj6sa0gC82YwQKduvcgOEaAjAAMADSubkqeqoLq4uyUGOyhRm6mzCRIuhBpzgA8ACpBSADSSBAAHmTAACZQSADWEPxolEi5AHwAFGgyAFbi+XUN4oUAlE6tSF3dANr1-AC6oSnmUmBO6ZntlvbMEAUeKt5CIsPyoQD0Z0hLaSviK3LkoRkkm1Y7e8pePvDsoxdIAHc0ORajUQDUyrx4GRKuISAALbgAiHkbiPHA4AxAA)